# How to blur an element without having its blur cover its surrounding elements when using filter: blur()?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the basic example I've provided, I'm blurring the `main` div using `filter: blur()`, however, the blurred black color goes over my pink `header` div. I was wondering if there's a way to avoid this unwanted effect?

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: pink;
}
.main {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background-color: black;
filter: blur(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the filter need to be applied on the content of the div or only for this background color? In that case, applying the background + filter on a pseudo element and setting overflow hidden on the div would do. But for this effect, you may also consider box-shadow or even a radial-gradient

Comment: @Kaiido Well I used a div with black color as an example but in my real case, I'm applying the blur on a video element. I could also apply something on the parent element of the video element. I just need the video to be used as a blurred background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your blurred content inside a container on which you'll set the `overflow` property to `hidden`:

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: pink;
}
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
}
video {
filter: blur(50px);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm" muted autoplay loop></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as the `blur` property accepts only a radius value, I don't see any other way than 'hack' your way out of this, see my suggestions below in the code comments.

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: pink;
margin-bottom:30px; /* add a margin to the element to push it away from the blur */
}
.main {
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background-color: black;
filter: blur(10px); /* reduce the blur radius ? */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```